# Argument 'd3Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, ng-controller

I know multiple people have asked this questions and i've tried their solution but it hasn't helped. i'm trying to use d3 but it gives me this error:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

controller

```
app.controller('d3Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [10,20,30,40,60];
}]);
```

directive:

```
app.directive('barsChart', function ($parse) {
     //explicitly creating a directive definition variable
     //this may look verbose but is good for clarification purposes
     //in real life you'd want to simply return the object {...}
     var directiveDefinitionObject = {
         //We restrict its use to an element
         //as usually  <bars-chart> is semantically
         //more understandable
         restrict: 'E',
         //this is important,
         //we don't want to overwrite our directive declaration
         //in the HTML mark-up
         replace: false,
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           //converting all data passed thru into an array
           var data = attrs.chartData.split(',');
           //in D3, any selection[0] contains the group
           //selection[0][0] is the DOM node
           //but we won't need that this time
           var chart = d3.select(element[0]);
           //to our original directive markup bars-chart
           //we add a div with out chart stling and bind each
           //data entry to the chart
            chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
             .selectAll('div')
             .data(data).enter().append("div")
             .transition().ease("elastic")
             .style("width", function(d) { return d + "%"; })
             .text(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
           //a little of magic: setting it's width based
           //on the data value (d) 
           //and text all with a smooth transition
         } 
      };
      return directiveDefinitionObject;
   });
```

index.html

```
    <head>
            <style>
                .chart {
                background: #eee;
                padding: 3px;
            }

                .chart div {
              width: 0;
              transition: all 1s ease-out;
              -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
              -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
            }

                .chart div {
              font: 10px sans-serif;
              background-color: steelblue;
              text-align: right;
              padding: 3px;
              margin: 5px;
              color: white;
              box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
            }
            </style>

          <!-- Bring in Bootstrap css so things look nice by default -->

            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-resource.js"></script>

            <script type= "text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
            <script type= "text/javascript" src="d3controller.js"></script>
            <script type= "text/javascript" src="d3directive.js"></script>

        </head>
<body>
     <div ng-controller="d3Ctrl">
          <bars-chart chart-data="myData"  ></bars-chart>
     </div>
</body>
```

I basically copied this example off the internet and it's throwing me:
Error: ng:areq Bad Argument
Argument 'd3Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined
I'm not sure what is wrong here, if I don't add this my app is working fine. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## Do Not Use Angular.min.js

The minified version of Angular is for production not for development. It will give you strage errors that are difficult to read. change this line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
```

### JQuery

Sometimes JQuery and Angular dont play nice so try swapping your vertion of Bootstrap to Angular Bootstrap. [Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is a link to it.

## Conclusion

Make these basic changes to your app and you will probably have a much easier time with development [Here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight) is a link to a good Angular file structure that I have been using. I have also made use of the angular bootstrap and full versions of AngularJS.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the help!
I didn't save the file properly and it wasn't reading the correct file. So i'm able to solve that problem and there is hint of chart showing but it's not fully there yet!

Comment: Sorry its not directly the answer you're looking for but I thought doing some of these things could make the error more obvious.